# Uso della virgola

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Supposto che la virgola lì sotto produca la descritta variazione di significato, come si legge la proposizione senza virgola? Nell'un modo o nell'altro?

[image]

Comment: La virgola, si mette fin troppo spesso ;-)

Comment: Mi chiedo se Cortázar padroneggiasse bene l'italiano o se Maccioni dia per scontato che italiano e spagnolo funzionino allo stesso modo, fin nelle virgole.

Comment: La frase *scritta* è ambigua; se *detta*, chi la pronuncia metterebbe una breve pausa dopo “che ha” oppure dopo "la donna”. In ogni caso, una frase senza contesto può avere ambiguità che il contesto toglierebbe. L'esempio classico è “la vecchia porta la sbarra”. Nessuno ha notato l'orrido *della inutilità”?

Comment: @egreg Che significa 'Nessuno ha notato l'orrido «della inutilità»'? C'è qualcosa che mi sfugge, forse.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider sarebbe meglio con l'apostrofo: "dell'inutilità".

Comment: @ElberichSchneider In italiano si dice *dell'inutilità* se non si è in una situazione speciale in cui si vuole dare enfasi particolare alla parola *inutilità*, che non è certamente il caso qui.

Comment: Avrei messo una virgola nel titolo dell'articolo: «Salviamo la virgola, porta del pensiero». :-)

Answer (score 10):

La frase senza virgola è ambigua. Non credo che esista nessuna regola "standard" di risoluzione di queste ambiguità.

Tuttavia, la versione che mette la virgola dopo la parola "donna" è secondo me leggermente più naturale, per cui io sono portato ad intendere quella (quanto meno, leggendo per la prima volta la frase io ho inteso in quel significato; ho dovuto rileggere con più attenzione per convincermi che ce n'era anche un altro).

Comment: Anch'io la leggevo con la virgola dopo "donna", ma forse è più per il fatto che per caso va a capo in quel punto.